# sys_id arrays to is one of not displaying records

Tags: servicenow

I am creating one report. In report condition I am using 'is one of' and passing sys_id array by calling client callable script include  javascript: new GetMoreInfoUpdatedChangeTickets().getSysIds();as. I can see sys_ids as "Data source conditions:Sys ID in 60a219744fc73200d6940e428110c72b". But corresponding record is not getting displayed. But corresponding sys_id record is available.

Answer (score 3):

I think I see the issue here. Unfortunately, that is not how client-callable script includes typically work. Script includes, even client-callable ones, ALWAYS execute on the server. They are meant to be called via an asynchronous GlideAjax call from a client-side script.

For more information on this, I encourage you to have a look at [this article](https://snprotips.com/blog/2016/2/6/gliderecord-client-side-vs-server-side) on GlideAjax.

However, luckily for you, your actual query executes on the server, not the client. So a Script Include **is** probably the right way to go, but the problem you're facing is (probably) that by making it a GlideAjax script include, you're telling ServiceNow to override the constructor (initialize()) method, but leave it as a Class.

---

Since you say you're getting a sys_id returned, it's possible that what I described isn't the issue, and this solution won't work. However, I don't have enough information to give any other answer; so if that's the case, please run the query that isn't showing you the correct results, then right-click on the last query breadcrumb at the top of the list, and click "Copy Query", then **paste the query** in a reply on this thread (replying specifically to my comment so I get notified) so I can have a look.

Please also obviously **provide the code in your script include** so I can help you troubleshoot.

---

EDIT: 
Now what you've added your code in a reply to this comment, I can see several issues.

Your original:

```
var GetMoreInfoUpdatedChangeTickets = Class.create();
GetMoreInfoUpdatedChangeTickets.prototype = {
    initialize:   function() {
    }, getSysIds: function getMyGroupMembers() {
        var ga = new GlideRecord('sysapproval_group');
        ga.addQuery('parent.sys_class_name', '=', 'change_request');
        ga.query();
        gs.log("TotalRecords1 Before:: " + ga.getRowCount());
        var sysIdArray = [];
        while (ga.next()) {
            sysIdArray.push(ga.sys_id);
        }
        return sysIdArray;
    }, type:      'GetMoreInfoUpdatedChangeTickets'
}
```

Here are all of the changes I made to your code, and an explanation for each:

First, on **line 5** in the code below, I've changed how your member function (aka: "method") is declared. You had it declared like so: 
`getSysIds: function getMyGroupMembers() {}`
So here, you've essentially given it two names and declared it in two ways at once. 
Normally, a function is declared like this: 
`function functionName(args) {}`
However, inside of an object (or in this case, a Class - which is an object with a constructor that returns copies of itself using the "new" keyword) we declare functions like this: 
`functionName: function(args) {},`
So as you can see in the code below, I've made that adjustment for you.

Next, on **line 8** below, I've removed the redundant '=' operator from your `addQuery()` method call, as "=" is implied when not specified. This isn't required, but it looks cleaner this way. 
(I've also renamed your GlideRecord variable from `ga` to `grApprovalGroup` throughout, so that it makes more sense.)

I've moved the declaration of `sysIdArray` to the top of the function for consistency with how it's executed (and for clarity). This is also not required, but is generally recommended.

**Line 12** below, in your original code, looked like this: 
`sysIdArray.push(grApprovalGroup.sys_id);`
However, since `gr.sys_id` is an **object** (type: "GlideElement" - [documentation here](https://developer.servicenow.com/app.do#!/api_doc?v=istanbul&id=c_GlideElementScopedAPI)), this is pushing a **reference** to that object into the array. As the **string value** property of that object (the one at location `gr.sys_id` changes, **so does the string value property of each and every element in the array**, since every single element is a **reference** to the same object! More information on this, in an article (which I wrote) [that you can find here](https://snprotips.com/blog/2017/4/9/always-use-getters-and-setters). 
Suffice it to say that this is not a good idea, and will result in a list of the same sys_id over and over! To fix this, we simply use the best-practice recommended "getter" method (as the article I linked recommends), as you can see on line 12 in the code below.

```
var GetMoreInfoUpdatedChangeTickets = Class.create();
GetMoreInfoUpdatedChangeTickets.prototype = {
    initialize: function() {
    },
    getSysIds:  function() {
        var sysIdArray = [];
        var grApprovalGroup = new GlideRecord('sysapproval_group');
        grApprovalGroup.addQuery('parent.sys_class_name', 'change_request');
        grApprovalGroup.query();

        while (grApprovalGroup.next()) {
            sysIdArray.push(grApprovalGroup.getValue('sys_id'));
        }
        return sysIdArray;
    },
    type:       'GetMoreInfoUpdatedChangeTickets'
};
```

Finally, we need to actually extract the function from the class and rename it so the script include itself is just the function.

```
function GetMoreInfoUpdatedChangeTickets() {
    var sysIdArray = [];
    var grApprovalGroup = new GlideRecord('sysapproval_group');
    grApprovalGroup.addQuery('parent.sys_class_name', 'change_request');
    grApprovalGroup.query();

    while (grApprovalGroup.next()) {
        sysIdArray.push(grApprovalGroup.getValue('sys_id'));
    }
    return sysIdArray;
}
```

Since you can't use the "new" keyword in query javascript, it's necessary to define it like this (without the class), and once we've done that we can re-enable the "client callable" option you had enabled previously.

Once you've done that, you should be able to go to the following URL, and see your query script in action:

https://YOUR_INSTANCE.service-now.com/sysapproval_group_list.do?sysparm_query=sys_id%3Djavascript%3A%20GetMoreInfoUpdatedChangeTickets()%3B

Comment: After implementing your suggestion my code is similar as below: var GetMoreInfoUpdatedChangeTickets= Class.create(); GetMoreInfoUpdatedChangeTickets.prototype = { initialize: function() { }, getSysIds : function getMyGroupMembers(){ var ga = new GlideRecord('sysapproval_group'); ga.addQuery('parent.sys_class_name', '=', 'change_request'); ga.query(); gs.log("TotalRecords1 Before:: " + ga.getRowCount()); var sysIdArray = []; while(ga.next()){ sysIdArray.push(ga.sys_id); } return sysIdArray; }, type: 'GetMoreInfoUpdatedChangeTickets' };

Comment: There, I updated my initial comment with more info and the solution. Please see it, and try to provide the requested information next time if you want help.

Comment: Its working after converting to array grApprovalGroup.getValue('sys_id').toString()